# Given the square matrix $A$ and that $\ker(A^2) = \ker(A^3)$ does this imply that $\ker(A^3) = \ker(A^4)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Consider a square matrix $A$ with $\ker(A^2) = \ker(A^3)$. Is $\ker(A^3) = \ker(A^4)$? Justify your answer.

I understand that $\ker(A^3)$ is at least a subset of $\ker(A^4)$.  I am just not sure how to show that they are equal given that $\ker(A^2) = \ker(A^3)$ (rather than $\ker(A^2)$ being a subset of $\ker(A^3)$).

I know that if the vector $x$ is in $\ker(A^4)$ then $A^4 x=0$ and $A^2 A^2 x = 0$.  From this is is pretty obvious that $\ker(A^2)$ must be a subset of $\ker(A^4)$.  I just am not sure where to go from here in proving / disproving what was asked in the question.  Any suggestions / hints / advice?

Answer (score 3):

Erick Wong gave a good hint, but since I didn't find the hints particularly illuminating myself, I thought I would add a more explicit answer for future people.

As the OP notes, $\ker A^3 \subset \ker A^4$, since if $A^3x=0$, then certainly $A^4x=A(A^3x)=A0=0$. Thus we just need to show $\ker A^4 \subset \ker A^3$.

> Then if $A^4x =0$, then $Ax\in \ker A^3=\ker A^2$. Thus $A^2(Ax)=A^3x=0$. Thus $\ker A^4\subset \ker A^3$, and $\ker A^3 = \ker A^4$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: For any vector $x$ of the appropriate dimension, $x$ is in $\text{ker}(A^4)$ if and only if $Ax$ is in $\text{ker}(A^3)$...

Comment: Hmm.  I still don't see how that gets me much closer.  Now I can also say A*A^3 x = 0 which shows that ker(A^4) is a subset of ker(A^3) which I knew before.  Maybe this is a trick equation and we can not say that ker(A^3) = ker(A^4).

Comment: @chasep255 If you know that $\text{ker}(A^4)$ is a subset of $\text{ker}(A^3)$ then you're already done, but I think you wrote that backwards.

Comment: @chasep255 Nothing you or I have written so far has made use of the essential assumption in your subject line.  Given that $Ax$ is in $\text{ker}(A^3)$, **what else do you know**?

Comment: Really, why the downvote?